# I need to test Regex value to match correctly for my input text

Tags: javascript, regex

My input values are:

> FRKK1111122222AAAAAAAAAAA33

- The total length is 27.
- I need to skip first 4 characters
- Then match 10 numbers
- Then 11 Letters
- Then 2 numbers from above input.

To match below condition:

Skip first 4 characters. for ex - FRKK then Check 1111122222 is number or not, Check AAAAAAAAAAA is letters or not Check 33 is number or not

---

I tried to break using substr and passing this string in function to match seprate values.

```
ischar(str){ 
    var letters = "^[a-zA-Z]*$";
    if(str.match(letters)){
      return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already validated the string and you want to get the parts you can use this pattern. [Here's](https://regex101.com/r/9xg1S0/1) the explanation.

```js
var re = /[\S]{4}(\d{10})([a-zA-Z]{11})(\d{2})/;
var str = 'FRKK1111122222AAAAAAAAAAA33';
var [str, first, second, third] = str.match(re);
console.log(first, second, third);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple regex test

```js
const str = 'FRKK1111122222AAAAAAAAAAA33';
const check = /^.{4}\d{10}[a-z]{11}\d{2}$/i;
console.log(check.test(str));
```

---

Note that

```
var letters = "^[a-zA-Z]*$";
```

is not a regex but a plain string, you're currently passing a string to `match`. A regex in javascript is constructed with `/<regex expression here>/`, not enclosed by `'` or `"`.